# Testing facebook connect on localhost

Tags: facebook, api

I'm trying to test a facebook connect on my localhost. In the app settings in the facebook developer page I tried changing "Website with facebook login" to `http://localsitename:8888` but I am given an error:

```
Error
Site URL must be a URL with a valid domain.
```

I have read where others have managed to do this successfully. Has anyone found a work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Facebook accepts only `localhost` as a domain name without any dots in it.

Make your local site’s name something with a dot in it, then it should work fine – `localsite.name`, `mytestsite.local` or even `foo.bar` …

Comment: I've marked this as correct. However, in the end I just put the live domain into the facebook dev centre and set my host file to point to my dev site with the liveURL. Not ideal but I was able to complete the work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

CBroe's answer worked well!

If you are working with **xampp**, you can edit `\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` and add another virtual host. also edit `\windows\system32\driver\etc\hosts` file and add a reference to the new host.

**hosts:** added

`technotronic.fb 127.0.0.1`

**httpd-vhosts.conf:** 
  added

```
<VirtualHost *>
        DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/technotronic"
        ServerName technotronic.fb
        <Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs/technotronic">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Is this dot needed or would be "technotronic" as ServerName also ok?

Comment: dot is needed in order for facebook to allow this address as a site name. the only one word address facebook is allowing is localhost.

Comment: Thanks, yet it was the dot - not it works for me too.