# Changing the localhost to a custom url in Jboss

Tags: jboss7.x

I am trying to create a login module that could use facebook login too . I am using Jboss 7.1 as my server and i run it from inside eclipse and my OS is Ubuntu.

The problem now is that Facebook doesn't seem to accept requests when the url is of type say

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/
```

and expects something of the form `http://localhost.test/myApp`.

([Testing facebook connect on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641703/testing-facebook-connect-on-localhost))

**My problem is that I am not aware of how to change the above pattern (from localhost:8080 to say localhost.mysite) in JBOSS server.**

Can someone let me know on how this has to be done.

Thanks

Comment: you might want to refer to the comment on the answer to the question you have added URL of in your question. (y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -b parameter to specify the bind address JBoss should use, see:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Admin+Guide?_sscc=t

This switch should be available in the Eclipse JBoss Tools as well.

I discovered just recently that JBoss 7.x (as well as JBoss EAP 6) does not accept connections from outside if you don't specify the Host/IP-Address via the aforementioned parameter; even responses to web service requests it sends itself are not received.

If you want to change things like the web service endpoint host, port etc. you can do this via standalone.xml. For Web Services or ReST you simply specify subsections whose schema is defined by the XSDs located in the docs/schema folder (jboss-as-webservices_1_1, jboss-as-jaxrs_1_0 respectively ). For convenience (auto-completion, validation) you can put them into an XML catalog and registered the catalog within Eclipse.